# shellcheck on sonarcloud (plugin)

Tags: bash, code-analysis, sonarlint, sonarcloud, shellcheck

I use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) in order to validate my bash scripts.

I have a project that is made in bash and I want to scan it with ShellCheck in SonarCloud.

When I use SonarCloud für analysis it shows `The main branch has no lines of code.`.

Currently, I automatically calling [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) by the CI but I want to have the Result on SonarCloud.

I know that there is [sonar-shellcheck-plugin](https://github.com/emerald-squad/sonar-shellcheck-plugin) **for SonarQube**(self-hosted)
but is it possible to use this on **SonarCloud**?

If so, how is this possible?